# Screen Sharing between two android devices

Tags: screen-sharing

Is there any way to share the screen from one device to another?

Sharing screen means not just accessing data from one to another device but it should be real time, suppose If I open any Application/file/video on my device the same should be seen on all shared devices as I see on my device?

For desktop environments I have seen teamviewer, join.me – but the opposite device should have access to my file explorer. Did anyone come across a solution?

Comment: Are you looking to share video/images etc, or share the "desktop" on the devices? Have you tried any screen sharing apps from the Play Store, any of these: http://appcrawlr.com/android-apps/best-apps-screen-sharing

Comment: @RossC tried it,but as i mentioned there is no applications which let me to explore files during sharing

Comment: Maybe some [VNC server](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=vnc%20server) offers a suitable solution for you?